# SQL Delete command not actually deleting any records from table?

Tags: sql-server-2005

When try to delete records from a SQL Server 2005 table, the record are not really deleted even though query executed successfully. After delete command execution, when i query the table, all the records are reloaded automatically in the table.

What could be the reason behind this?  Any rights/permission issue?

Edit:

```
Delete from dbo.TrnPartAwarding

Select * from dbo.TrnPartAwarding
```

after executing above statements...

```
Select * from dbo.TrnPartAwarding
```

...brings all the data back again.

Comment: Chances are your query is incorrect, or you have a hanging transaction. If you didn't have permission, it would tell you as much. Can you post the query and sample data?

Comment: Have you tried with `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.TrnPartAwarding` ?

Comment: A hanging transaction could only have that effect if `read uncommitted` or snapshot isolation are in use. Do you have any `INSTEAD OF` triggers on that table?

Comment: @malinois: Truncate is not the same as deleting all the records. A truncate resets identity column values.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not using a WHERE clause?

When doing a delete, even if no records match the WHERE clause and nothing is deleted, it is considered successful.

Or, you are deleting from one database and reading from a different database.

Answer (score 0):

First->always use where statement with delete clausie.
Try commit command after executing the query.
check if table is getting loaded from other process.